# Does .Net / Visual Studio support foreign language keywords for non English speaking cultures?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, translation

I was wondering whether the majority of non English speaking cultures, especially in Europe, tend to develop their .Net code in their native language or in English?

My personal assumption is that there would be a tendency to keep the code in English in order to ensure maintenance is possible across teams operating in different cultures. Also, would the fact that so much of the language and documentation provided is in English also be a major bearing in how the solution was provided?

Does Visual Studio also provide a means to provide .Net keywords as a localised version so that for instance a German developer can write "class" as "Klasse"?

Comment: .Net localisation means both documentation and Type name translation. class/klasse is a C# linguistic thing, quite something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst you could create your class names and variables (and of course comments) in a native language, the language keywords are fixed by the language specification itself.

C# is in fact an [ECMA standard (334)](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-334.htm).

Comment: If I remember correctly, MS Office once localized the VB-Script object names. That lead to problems when you were trying to run macro developed with the english version on a german office. What a PITA.

Comment: So there is no way that Visual Studio can convert a local language representation of the keywords into CLR code before presenting uniformally to the JIT compiler?

Comment: In short, no. You wouldn't even be able to compile it.

Comment: That's a shame. I'm not from the UK, but it would be cool if C# had a "whilst" statement. :)

Answer (score 3):

No. C# is it's own language. The keywords are not translated.

I am Norwegian and I prefer documentation and manuals in English. I don't know many developers here that prefer Norwegian to English in technical literature.

Personally, I also prefer to give variables and classes English names, because somehow  it flows better when reading the source code.

VBA and Excel functions are sometimes translated, and it is very hard for me to guess what the functions and keywords are called in Norwegian. Also it makes it impossible to reuse templates from international sources.